# Can someone explain the difference between Add_member and $hashTable.Something for a hashtable?

Tags: powershell, properties, hashtable

Lets say I have a hashtable:

```
$HashTable = @{}
```

Now, when I want to add something to the Hashtable I usually do it like this:

```
$HashTable.Something = 'Something'
```

When I test $hashTable it will show this output:

```
$HashTable

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                     
----                           -----                                                                                                                                     
Something                      Something
```

A Colleague of mine used Add-Member in stead:

```
$HashTable | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'SomethingAddMember' -NotePropertyValue 'SomethingAddMember'
```

It works, but when you look at $HashTable it will still only show this:

```
$HashTable

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                     
----                           -----                                                                                                                                     
Something                      Something
```

When I run this $HashTable.SomethingAddMember it will show up:

```
$HashTable.SomethingAddMember
```

Why is it not showing up in the HashTable itself? When I convert it to Json it's there again! How confusing can this be, or am I missing something??

```
$HashTable | ConvertTo-Json
{
    "Something":  "Something",
    "SomethingAddMember":  "SomethingAddMember"
}
```

Is it because Add-Member adds a new property to the HashTable instead of the Keys with Values? How can this happen like this?

Comment: "Is it because Add-Member adds a new property to the HashTable instead of the Keys with Values?" - yes, that's exactly why :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's good information here already, but let me break it down conceptually:

**The *entries* of a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) (key-value pairs) are distinct from its .NET type's *members* (properties, methods, events)**.

Hashtable entries are *data*, accessible via the [`System.Collections.Hashtable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Hashtable) type's *members*, notably the `.Keys` and `.Values` properties and the *parameterized* `.Item` property, which PowerShell (like C#) surfaces syntactically via ***index* syntax**:

- That is, you can get an entry's value by using its key inside `[...]`, as syntactic sugar for `.Item(...)`; e.g.,
  `@{ foo = 42 }['foo']` is a shortcut to `@{ foo = 42 }.Item('foo')`

***Additionally*, PowerShell allows you to access entry values *with dot notation*, using `.`**, the [*member*-access operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#member-access-operator-) - even though what you're accessing isn't a *member*, but a hashtable entry; e.g.
`@{ foo = 42 }.foo` is equivalent to `@{ foo = 42 }['foo']`.

Note that the **inverse is *not* true: You can *not* use index notation to access an object's true properties**: e.g., `([pscustomobject] @{ foo = 42 })['foo']` does *not* work as intended: by default, it quietly evaluates to `$null`, and with [`Set-StrictMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode)  `-Version 2` or higher in effect it causes an error - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73449134/45375).

In other words:

- **PowerShell's `.` (dot notation) can access *both***:

  - **type *members* *by name***
  - ***entry values* by *key***, in the case of hashtables and `[ordered]` hashtables - and, more generally, types that implement [`System.Collections.IDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IDictionary) interface or its generic counterpart, [`System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary-2).<sup>[1]</sup>
- If there is a *name conflict*, the *entry* access takes precedence - e.g, `@{ Count = 42 }.Count` returns `42` rather than the value of the type-native `Count` property reflecting the number of entries; to access the latter, prefix the property name with `get_` and invoke that as a *method*: `@{ Count = 42 }.get_Count()` returns `1`, the entry count.

Note: The members that [`Add-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member) adds to an object aren't technically *.NET type* members (type-native properties and methods), but in PowerShell *they act as such*. (Such members, which are a feature of [PowerShell's ETS (Extended Type System)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763), are known to PowerShell only, and are of necessity maintained separately from the object they're associated with.)

In other words: **Your `Add-Member` call added a new *property* (`NoteProperty`) rather than an *entry* to the hashtable instance**, alongside the instance's type-native properties such as `.Count`, `.Keys`, and `.Values`.

**With respect to *surfacing* entries vs. members:**

- Since a hashtable's default output formatting show its *entries only*, any (ETS) *members* you've added won't show in the output - you'd have to access the `.SomethingAddMember` property explicitly; you can also see it via *reflection*, using [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member) (`$Hashtable | Get-Member SomethingAddMember`)
- **While ETS properties generally rarely surface, they do in *serialization contexts***, such as when using [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json), and **in the case of hashtables (dictionaries) you get a *mix* of ETS properties and *entries***, which is what you saw:

  - **In many contexts, PowerShell treat hashtables (dictionaries) as if they were regular objects, where the hashtable's *entries* - rather than the hashtable object's true type-native properties - are used *in lieu of properties***.
  - However, *ETS* properties are still included,<sup>[2]</sup> resulting in the aforementioned mix.

---

<sup>[1] Strangely, dot notation does *not* work if the *key* type happens to be `[object]`, though that isn't typical, given that the very point of a *generic* type/interface is to use *specific* types - see [GitHub issue #15997](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15997).</sup>

<sup>[2] Since PowerShell 7.2, `ConvertTo-Json` no longer serializes ETS properties for `[datetime]` and `[string]` instances (see [GitHub PR #15665](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/15665)), but other serialization cmdlets such as [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv) still do.

On a related note, as of PowerShell 7.2, when `ConvertTo-Json` does include ETS properties, it accidentally uses the type-native property's value if the ETS property happens to *override* the type-native one - see [GitHub issue #13998](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13998).</sup>

Answer (score 2):

@mathiasrjessen has explained it. Here are some commands that will show it.

```
$Hash = @{'A' = 'now'; 'B' = 'then'}
$Hash
$Hash | Get-Member -MemberType Property,NoteProperty | Select-Object -Property Name,MemberType | Format-Table * -Force
$Hash.Something = 'Something'
$Hash
$Hash | Get-Member -MemberType Property,NoteProperty | Select-Object -Property Name,MemberType | Format-Table * -Force
$Hash | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'SomethingAddMember' -NotePropertyValue 'SomethingAddMemberValue'
$Hash
$Hash.SomethingAddMember
$Hash | Get-Member -MemberType Property,NoteProperty | Select-Object -Property Name,MemberType | Format-Table * -Force
```