# How do I convert a powershell hashtable to an object?

Tags: powershell, hashtable, pscustomobject

Some hashtables in PowerShell, such as those imported with `Import-PowerShellDataFile`, would be much easier to navigate if being a PSCustomObject instead.

```
@{
    AllNodes = @(
        @{
            NodeName = 'SRV1'
            Role = 'Application'
            RunCentralAdmin = $true
        },
        @{
            NodeName = 'SRV2'
            Role = 'DistributedCache'
            RunCentralAdmin = $true
        },
        @{
            NodeName = 'SRV3'
            Role = 'WebFrontEnd'
            PSDscAllowDomainUser = $true
            PSDscAllowPlainTextPassword = $true
            CertificateFolder = '\\mediasrv\Media'
        },
        @{
            NodeName = 'SRV4'
            Role = 'Search'
        },
        @{
            NodeName = '*'
            DatabaseServer = 'sql1'
            FarmConfigDatabaseName = '__FarmConfig'
            FarmContentDatabaseName = '__FarmContent'
            CentralAdministrationPort = 1234
            RunCentralAdmin = $false
        }
    );
    NonNodeData = @{
        Comment = 'No comment'
    }
}
```

When imported it will become a hashtable of hashtables

```
$psdnode = Import-PowerShellDataFile .\nodefile.psd1

$psdnode

Name                           Value
----                           -----
AllNodes                       {System.Collections.Hashtable, System.Collect...
NonNodeData                    {Comment}

$psdnode.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Hashtable                                System.Object
```

and the data structure will be just weird when navigating by property name.

Comment: "the data structure will be just weird when navigating by property name." - can you tell us more about what you mean? Dictionaries (including hashtables) are generally _easier_ to iterate/traverse than objects with dynamic member sets.

Comment: Okay, I'm asking about _your preference_, care to share? What is it that makes it so horrible to work with? What is it that you can't do with a hashtable that you could do with a psobject? :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen That depends on your preference :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen For navigating the data structure, the code will be much smaller (eq. cleaner) to read.

Comment: Are you sure? PowerShell has a dictionary adapter that exposes the keys as properties, so you can interrogate it the exact same way as a custom object: `foreach($node in $psdnode.AllNodes){ Write-Host $node.NodeName }` :)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the possibilities. But I'd rather not iterate through an object if I already now what property to use...

Comment: The only thing I'm iterating over here is the array contained in the `AllNodes` entry of the root dictionary. `$psdnode.AllNodes` <- exact same syntax as if `$psdnode` was a custom object. `$node.NodeName` <- exact same syntax as if `$node` was a custom object.

Comment: Yes, but I don't need to iterate as all now :)

Comment: So what is it that you'd want to do once the hashtable(s) have been turned into custom objects? What code would you write?

Comment: The thing I prefer to do is to filter instead of iterating as in $nodes.AllNodes | Where NodeName -eq SRV1

Comment: And that's what I'm trying to tell you: you can already do that with hashtables :) `$psdnode.AllNodes |Where-Object NodeName -eq SRV1` _already works_ with the data you've presented

Comment: Ah, sweet :) Then it's perhaps just the pivoted view that I prefer when outputting the data.

Comment: yes if only Format-Table / Format-List would work with a hashtable..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's good information in the existing answers, but given your question's generic title, let me try a **systematic overview**:

- **You do *not* need to convert a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) to a `[pscustomobject]` instance in order to use *dot notation* to drill down into its entries (properties)**, as discussed in the comments and demonstrated in [iRon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73894874/45375).

  - A simple example:

    ```bash
    @{ top = @{ nested = 'foo' } }.top.nested  # -> 'foo'
    ```
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68928211/45375) for more information.
- In fact, ***when possible*, use of hashtables is *preferable* to  `[pscustomobject]`s**, because:

  - they are lighter-weight than `[pscustomobject]` instances (use less memory)
  - it is easier to construct them iteratively and add / remove entries on demand.

Note:

- The above doesn't just apply to the [`[hashtable]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Hashtable) type, but more generally to instances of types that implement the [`[System.Collections.IDictionary]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IDictionary) interface or its generic counterpart, [`System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary[TKey, TValue]]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary-2), notably including *ordered* hashtables (which are instances of type [`System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary), which PowerShell allows you to construct with *syntactic sugar* `[ordered] @{ ... }`).
- Unless noted, *hashtable* in the following section refers to *all* such types.

---

**In cases where you *do* need to convert a `[hasthable]` to a `[pscustomobject]`**:

While many standard cmdlets accept `[hasthable]`s *interchangeably* with `[pscustomobjects]`s, some do *not*, notably `ConvertTo-Csv` and `Export-Csv` (see [GitHub issue #10999](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10999) for a feature request to change that); in such cases, conversion to `[pscustomobject]` is a must.

**Caveat**: Hasthables can have keys of *any type*, whereas conversion to `[pscustomobject]` invariably requires using *string* "keys", i.e. *property names*. Thus, not all hashtables can be faithfully or meaningfully converted to `[pscustomobject]`s.

- **Converting *non-nested* hashtables to `[pscustomobject]`:**

  - The syntactic sugar PowerShell offers for `[pscustomobject]` literals (e.g., `[pscustomobject] @{ foo = 'bar'; baz = 42 }`) also works via *preexisting* hash; e.g.:

    ```bash
    $hash = @{ foo = 'bar'; baz = 42 } 
    $custObj = [pscustomobject] $hash   # Simply cast to [pscustomobject]
    ```
- **Converting *nested* hashtables, i.e. an object *graph*, to a `[pscustomobject]` graph:**

  - A simple, though limited and potentially expensive solution is the one shown in [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73894088/45375): Convert the hashtable to JSON with [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json), then reconvert the resulting JSON into a *`[pscustomobject]` graph* with [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json).

    - Performance aside, the fundamental limitation of this approach is that **type fidelity may be lost**, given that JSON supports only a few data types. While not a concern with a hashtable read via [`Import-PowerShellDataFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-powershelldatafile), a given hashtable may contain instances of types that have no meaningful representation in JSON.
  - You can overcome this limitation with a **custom conversion function, `ConvertFrom-HashTable`** (source code below); e.g. (inspect the result with `Format-Custom -InputObject $custObj`):

    ```bash
    $hash = @{ foo = 'bar'; baz = @{ quux = 42 } } # nested hashtable
    $custObj = $hash | ConvertFrom-HashTable # convert to [pscustomobject] graph
    ```

---

**`ConvertFrom-HashTable` source code:**

Note: Despite the name, the function generally supports instance of types that implement `IDictionary` as input.

```bash
function ConvertFrom-HashTable {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
    [System.Collections.IDictionary] $HashTable
  )
  process {
    $oht = [ordered] @{} # Aux. ordered hashtable for collecting property values.
    foreach ($entry in $HashTable.GetEnumerator()) {
      if ($entry.Value -is [System.Collections.IDictionary]) { # Nested dictionary? Recurse.
        $oht[[object] $entry.Key] = ConvertFrom-HashTable -HashTable $entry.Value # NOTE: Casting to [object] prevents problems with *numeric* hashtable keys.
      } else { # Copy value as-is.
        $oht[[object] $entry.Key] = $entry.Value
      }
    }
    [pscustomobject] $oht # Convert to [pscustomobject] and output.
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, excellent points and explanations :)

Comment: You know, I found this page trying to find a source to use as reference to support my own discovery of the Hashtable > Json > Json > PSCustomObject trick (I've referred to as the Json woop-dee-doo trick).

Comment: That function is SO good! but... `$Matches | ConvertFrom-HashTable` is incorrect due to a key named "0" (the primary regex match). I guess it causes an overwrite.

Comment: Thank you, @Hicsy. Good point about `$Matches` - the problem would have arisen with any hashtable whose keys are `[int]`-typed. I've fixed the function by adding `[object]` casts to the index expressions, which tells PowerShell not to interpret the index as a _positional_ one.

Answer (score 3):

#### What is the issue/question?

```
@'
@{
    AllNodes = @(
        @{
            NodeName = 'SRV1'
            Role = 'Application'
            RunCentralAdmin = $true
        },
        @{
            NodeName = 'SRV2'
            Role = 'DistributedCache'
            RunCentralAdmin = $true
        },
        @{
            NodeName = 'SRV3'
            Role = 'WebFrontEnd'
            PSDscAllowDomainUser = $true
            PSDscAllowPlainTextPassword = $true
            CertificateFolder = '\\mediasrv\Media'
        },
        @{
            NodeName = 'SRV4'
            Role = 'Search'
        },
        @{
            NodeName = '*'
            DatabaseServer = 'sql1'
            FarmConfigDatabaseName = '__FarmConfig'
            FarmContentDatabaseName = '__FarmContent'
            CentralAdministrationPort = 1234
            RunCentralAdmin = $false
        }
    );
    NonNodeData = @{
        Comment = 'No comment'
    }
}
'@ |Set-Content .\nodes.psd1
```

```
$psdnode = Import-PowerShellDataFile .\nodefile.psd1

$psdnode

Name                           Value
----                           -----
NonNodeData                    {Comment}
AllNodes                       {SRV1, SRV2, SRV3, SRV4…}
```

```
$psdnode.AllNodes.where{ $_.NodeName -eq 'SRV3' }.Role
WebFrontEnd
```

Answer (score 2):

A very simple way, that I discovered just yesterday, is to do a "double-convert" over JSON.

```
$nodes = Import-PowerShellDataFile .\nodes.psd1 | ConvertTo-Json | ConvertFrom-Json

$nodes

AllNodes
--------
{@{NodeName=SRV1; RunCentralAdmin=True; Role=Application}, @{NodeName=SRV2; RunCentralAdm...}

$nodes.GetType()   

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object
```